# Vector.Value is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#

I'm learning C# and ran into an error. All my methods are public. I'm emulating code from a book which states "Assume you have defined a class called Vector and that Vector is a reference type and has an int member variable called Value:" and it proceeds with the Program.cs code (which I copied). So I tried to emulate that Vector class and when I go to compile it says Vector.Value is inaccessible due to its protection level.

Program.cs:

```
using System;

namespace ReferenceType
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Vector x, y;
            x = new Vector();
            x.Value = 30;
            Console.WriteLine(y.Value);
            y.Value = 50;
            Console.WriteLine(x.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Vector.cs:

```
namespace ReferenceType
{
    public class Vector
    {
        private int Value;

        public int GetterSetter{
            get { return Value; }
            set { Value = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did `GetterSetter` come from? Why have you declare `Value` as private? Neither of those things seem to be mentioned in your "Assume:" quote.

Comment: You created a property `GetterSetter` instead of `Value`, and a private backing field named `Value`. I don't think that's what you wanted to do. Perhaps you wanted to write `public int Value {get;set;}` or `int _value; public int Value { get{return _value;} set {_value=value}};` ?

Comment: Properties in .NET aren't just getter/setters. They are significant and a part of the class's interface. They appear separately in the metadata, get serialized/deserialized, mapped to database tables etc. The backing field is just an implementation detail

Comment: I don't know what book it is, but if it says to create "an int member variable called Value", then you just need `public int Value;` The book is probably going to explain properties later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access a `private` member of class Vector, but you have a `public` property which exposes the `private` field `Value`, this should be used instead.

try this code,

```
using System;

namespace ReferenceType
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Vector x, y;
            x = new Vector();
            // Assign integer value to our public property "GetterSetter"
            x.GetterSetter= 30;
            // Access value of "Value" via "GetterSetter" property
            Console.WriteLine(x.GetterSetter);
            y.GetterSetter= 50;
            Console.WriteLine(y.GetterSetter);
        }
    }
}
```

Update it would be better to change your codes to that

```
using System;

namespace ReferenceType
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Vector x, y;
            x = new Vector();
            x.Value = 30;
            Console.WriteLine(x.Value);
            y.Value = 50;
            Console.WriteLine(y.Value);
        }
    }
}


//Vector.cs
using System;

namespace ReferenceType
{
    public class Vector
    {
        private int _value;

        public int Value{
            get { return _value; }
            set { _value = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more on Access Modifiers here [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx)

Comment: An explanation for this is, You are trying to access a `private` member from outside the class, you should actually be accessing `GetterSetter` which exposes the `private` field `Value`, and is also a `public` property.

Comment: @ColinM I wouldn't let my answer as simple as in the first publish :)

Comment: Thanks a lot... this makes sense. What threw me off is in the book it states x.Value = 30; // Value is a field defined in Vector class

Comment: I assumed field meant variable.. didn't realize it could mean method as well.

Comment: Is it possible that the book was setting the value from inside the class itself? `private` variables can be updated from inside the containing class, as `private` means it is scoped privately to that class. You can read more on Access Modifiers here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx

Comment: @juice also on your code you are trying to show on console y.Value when you haven't edited the y, but the x